# trying to create a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger that will store the timing of when a new row is inserted into a my employee's table. 
so far this is my code, but i keep getting errors.

trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_new_employee
AFTER INSERT ON employees
BEGIN
 insert into audit_cheker (date_create) values (sysdate());
END;
```

my table to store the timing for when inserting a new element:

```
create table audit_cheker(
date_create date
)
```

the error I've received is

> 4098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

Cause:

> A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
>              found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
>              failed for the trigger.

Action:

> Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
>              disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: . . `sysdate` does not take parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information you posted so far, it *should* work. Here's a test case:

```
SQL> create table audit_cheker
  2    (date_create date);

Table created.

SQL> create table employees as select empno, ename, deptno From emp;

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_new_employee
  2  AFTER INSERT ON employees
  3  BEGIN
  4   insert into audit_cheker (date_create) values (sysdate());
  5  END;
  6  /

Trigger created.
```

No problems so far. Let's test it:

```
SQL> insert into employees (empno, ename, deptno) values (1, 'LF', 10);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from employees where empno = 1;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 LF                 10

SQL> select * From audit_cheker;

DATE_CREATE
----------------
2020-04-24 07:18
```

As you can see, it *works*.

If trigger is invalid, try to recompile it:

```
SQL> alter trigger insert_new_employee compile;

Trigger altered.
```

If it still doesn't help, please, edit your initial message (the question you posted) and copy/paste **your** SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: I tried again this time I want to save the username of the person doing the inserting so I added few things. and after the trigger was created and I wanted to insert a new record an error came : 04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Which part of "copy/paste your SQL*Plus session" did you not understand?